AuthJS use different MongoDB Atlas database depending on request URL slug
I have a NextJS project that uses AuthJS (formerly NextAuth) based on this guide. I have managed to integrate Google OAuth2 and connected to MongoDB using this guide. Both of them work well with each other.
How can I customize the MongoDB Atlas database that is written to based on the origin of the login/signup request?
For example, AuthJS will by default create and write to the test database. Within there it will create the accounts, sessions and users collections. I am aware that I can just change the MongoDB URI to write to any other database. But if a request is originating from localhost:3000/organization1 how can I use direct NextAuth to use only the organization1 database for this particular request and create it's collections in there?
Then obviously, if a request originates from localhost:3000/organization2 use the organization2 database.
My current guess is to modify the backend at app/api/auth/[...nextauth] which currently looks like:
import { handlers } from '@/auth'; // Referring to the auth.ts created in this guide https://authjs.dev/getting-started/installation
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

and then detect the last portion of the URL. To do this I have:
const orgName = decodeURIComponent(req.nextUrl.pathname.split('/').pop());

But how do I send this to the AuthJS handlers? How do I get AuthJS to write to a different database based on the slug/path of the request origin?
